# Can i put multiple text boxes in an alert box in ios?

Tags: ios, alertview

can I put multiple text input boxes on the alert box in iOS?

Comment: Yes, you can. Why do you need this? There's a set layout style for login prompts if that's what you want.

Comment: `UIAlertView` already supports 1 or 2 text fields. Please read the docs for `UIAlertView`.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to write or use a custom alert view that has the text fields that you need.  If you only need 1 text field (or username/password) you can still use UIAlertView by setting the [alertViewStyle property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html).

There are custom alert views already written, such as [this one](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible.
Just add UITextField as subviews to the UIAlertView.
Set the tag for each UITextField, in order to retrieve the entered text later.

```
    UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    UITextField *textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 50.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    textField1.tag=0;
    textField1.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField1.delegate=self;

    [alert addSubview:textField1];

    UITextField *textField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 85.0, 260.0, 25.0)]; 
    textField2.tag=1;
    textField2.delegate=self;
    textField2.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    [alert addSubview:textField2];

    [alert show];
```

PLEASE NOTE that this is bad practice as it relies on UIAlertView being a subclass of UIView. As pointed out by MusiGenesis below, it won't work from iOS 7 onwards.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What happens when iOS 7 (or whatever version) comes out and alert views look or act differently? The `UIAlertView` is not meant to have random subviews added to it. It may work now but that doesn't mean it's a good approach.

Comment: @rmaddy: very prophetic of you - it appears that in the iOS 7 beta 2, you can't add subviews to a `UIAlertView` at all.

Answer (score 0):

if you want 2 text boxes, you can use login style, but set second item secureTextEntry to NO, refer to
http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/uialertviews-with-textfields.1355954/